# Using SQL Alias vs Inner Join, what is the difference?

Tags: sql

In http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp, it mentions using alias to do the following query,

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.CustomerName
FROM 
    Customers, Orders
WHERE 
    Customers.CustomerName = "Around the Horn" 
    AND Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
```

This confuses me with the usage of JOIN. Isn't this kind of query joining the columns from two tables? What are the differences between this kind of query and JOIN?

Comment: Don't use w3schools as a reference. The comma-separated join syntax was used in the 1980s. In 1992 a better syntax with explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN` etc.) was introduced. Use this instead. In your case: `FROM customers INNER JOIN orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID`. You can use alias names for tables, e.g. `c`for `customers` and `o` for `orders`. Then you can use `o.OrderID` instead of `Orders.OrderID` etc. which makes the query easier to read. E.g.: `FROM customers c JOIN orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID`

Comment: The standard quote for string literals is the single quote. You should not use double quotes. Some DBMS allow them, but it is better to stick to the standard. (MySQL allows double quotes for example, but only with a certain database setting. Change that setting and all your queries using double quotes on strings become invalid.)

Answer (score 2):

JOIN and alias are two differnt concept .. the alias is for create a substitutive name (shorter usually) for a more easy object reference and for a more easy read .. so you can have column name alias  or table name alias  eg:

```
select a.col1 
from my_table as a
```

a is an  alias  for the table  my_table
 or

```
select a.col1  as c1
from my_table as a
```

where c1 is an alias  for col1

JOIN are for build relation between table 
The Join can be implict or explict

In your code you are using implici join and the condition between the tables that keep the relation is based  on where  clause

but you could use a more espressive way using explict join

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN  Orders on Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID;
WHERE  Customers.CustomerName="Around the Horn"
```

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   correct  .. thanks  .. answer  updated  adding the  where clause and chaning the on condition

Answer (score 1):

> Both the same, there is no difference.

There are differences only in **readability**. 
In my opinion, PLSQL(ORACLE) developer choosing **alias** when writing queries then TSQL(SQL Server) developer choosing by `Join`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is there is no difference between your query and an inner join but many times, your write queries between tables where the relationships are not explicitly defined or a table may not require a relationship. In those cases, you would use a left join to return data from a first table and zero to many items from the table on the right. Using your format, makes that a lot more difficult to write and read. As for table Aliases, when writing self joins for example, you will need to use them so understanding them is essential.